# how to map a file to a shell command to be executed when you `cat` that file?

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to create a file and hook it up somehow to a shell command that gets executed whenever I `cat` that file.  So that the content of the file is the `stdout` of the shell command.

Something like `/proc/meminfo`.

Thanks

Comment: If that's all you want it to do, why not just use `cat`?

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I can't make out what you are asking. Are you saying you want a file created every time you run `cat`?

Comment: A hokey way to do it: In your `.bashrc`, add `alias cat='...'` where `...` tests for the special file(s) and does special things, else calls plain old `cat`.

Comment: I used to tell my Tech Support lead, "Give the customer what he needs, not what he asks for."  Can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to accomplish?  Do you really want to `cat` a file, or (for example) do you want to execute a command and pipe its output somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/proc/meminfo` lives in a special filesystem, `procfs`, that is implemented by the kernel. You could use FUSE to do something similar in userspace.

Answer (score 5):

We used to do this "back in the day" to make program generated `.finger` files.

Make your file into a named pipe. You use the `mknod` program to do this.

Then make a program, which can be a shell script, that continuously loops and writes content into that named pipe.

```
#!/bin/sh

mknod file p 2>/dev/null
while true; do
        (
                echo This is my file.
                echo There are many like it.
                echo But this one is mine.
        ) >> file
done
```

For some reason it won't let me kill that with Control-C, so I have to use Control-Z, then `kill %1`.

Now when you `cat file` you will get the contents, like this:

```
$ cat file 
This is my file.
There are many like it.
But this one is mine.
```

Comment: One of the many surprising results of the *"everything is a file"* philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should turn the problem around and write a shell command and execute that instead of cat to start with?  Anything "echo"'ed will appear on stdout.  The solution you are proposing is "not the unix way".

Comment: +1 - clarity is better than cleverness. If OP does what he is proposing for anything besides academic reasons future generations will be scratching heads, punching walls, and throwing monitors out windows when trying to cat files.